# Incorrect move syntax?

Tags: batch-file

I cannot figure out how to use the "move" command in batch. Here is what I'm doing:

```
@ECHO off
SET name=t
SET steam=C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\
SET buffer=C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\buffer\
SET desktop=C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\
SET s=%steam%%name%
SET b=%buffer%%name%
SET d=%desktop%%name%
ECHO Moving %s% to %buffer%
MOVE %s% %buffer%
ECHO Moving %d% to %steam%
MOVE %d% %steam%
ECHO Moving %b% to %desktop%
MOVE %b% %desktop%
PAUSE
```

Here is what it says:

```
Moving C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\t to C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\buffer\
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
Moving C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\t to C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
Moving C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\buffer\t to C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\
The system cannot find the file specified.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I am trying to move the folder "t" that is in C:\Program Files(x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\t to a "buffer" folder on the desktop. Then, I want to move the folder in the desktop named "t" to the steam path above, then "t" in the buffer folder to "t" in the desktop.

What I will be doing is using this to switch out a game's directory from the modded version to the non-modded version.

Comment: You need double quotes around the directory names that contain spaces.

Comment: @KenWhite Wow... That's quite embarrassing. That fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Your batch script is almost perfect, you only forgot to quote the directory lines. You have to do that because quite often your file and directory names will contain spaces, the interpreter uses these spaces to mark where one argument ends and another begins, therefore you must use double-quote to delimit the arguments.

```
SET file=moveme.yay
SET from=Z:\home\durden\documents\batch\a with space\
SET to=Z:\home\durden\documents\batch\b with space\
ECHO Moving
move "%from%%file%" "%to%%file%"
```

If you need to move to more complex scripting while staying on Windows, try PowerShell. (also `robocopy`[1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx) is a sort of updated version of move and copy, you could use that too)

<sub>Thanks for posting this question and bringing me such dos-nostalgia :)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation, but what do you mean by "move only works if both folders are on the same unit?" Do you mean on the same drive?  Also I know very little about Batch... in fact this is the first thing I've done with batch... I usually use Lua and a bit of Java.

Comment: Yes, but "unit" I mean both source and destination folders should be on the same "drive" (like C: for example). You would not have any problem because in your example, you seem to be using only the C drive.

Comment: Also, remember `move` actually **moves** the file, so there will be no copy left on the source folder. If you just want to copy it, use `copy` or `robocopy` instead.

Comment: *"The help command says move only works if both folders are on the same unit."* - Not true. The HELP says no such thing, and MOVE has no problem moving files from one drive to another.

Comment: @dbenham Here it does. ![cmd under wine/linux](http://s15.postimg.org/bm7tz6k4b/Captura_de_tela_14_11_2015_22_46_16.png)
But I am running it under wine after all...

Comment: By convention, [batch-file] is reserved for batch file programming on Windows, and wine/linux is certainly not Windows. That move limitation is a peculiarity of wine/linux, and not standard Windows behavior.

Comment: @dbenham removed that part from the answer, anything else?

Comment: My intentions were to move the file... As said above I'm trying to make it so I can just use that to switch out modded/non modded game files and it works... It's definitely not fancy but it works.